# What features of Gravity Rush 2 are no longer going to be available?

Tags: gravity-rush-2

So I've had *Gravity Rush 2* for a while and was waiting for all the DLC before I started it. when I did a couple of weeks ago I got an announcement in it that the online services were going to be discontinued in mid July (the message was saying how the shutdown date was being pushed back to then).

I am wondering what will longer going to be available after the online services is shut down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to be able to read Japanese, Sony made [an official statement](http://www.jp.playstation.com/info/software/nr-20170928-gravity-daze-2-ps4.html) regarding the ending of their online services on September 28th, 2017. If not,  Destructoid covered this topic fairly comprehensively in [a blog post](https://www.destructoid.com/reminder-gravity-rush-2-s-online-features-will-be-shut-down-this-month-480946.phtml) from January 4th, 2018.

> While the main story line and side missions, along with the trophies, will still be accessible, the following will be affected.
>
> - Receiving and sending challenges
> - Leaderboards
> - Receiving and posting Treasure Hunt hints
> - Receiving, posting and reviewing photos
> - Earning Dusty Tokens