# How do I earn Dusty Token rewards after the shutdown on the online services?

Tags: gravity-rush-2

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/333960/30879) when *Gravity Rush 2*'s Online Services shut down i will no longer be able to earn Dusty Tokens.

Out of all the Dusty Token Rewards I want to be the costumes, particularly since I can get back my school uniform I used to war all the time in the previous game.

If I will no longer no longer able to get Dusty Tokens when the Online services shut down, how will I be able to get these rewards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Destructoid article in the linked answer](https://www.destructoid.com/reminder-gravity-rush-2-s-online-features-will-be-shut-down-this-month-480946.phtml),

> The loss of the Dusty Tokens is a big one, as it results in unique photo items, tailsmans and costumes being permanently locked off, including the Unlimited Potential tailsman which allows unlimited gravity.

More specifically, the items that will be **permanently locked off** can be found via [this IGN article regarding Dusty Tokens](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gravity-rush-2/Dusty_Tokens) and their rewards,

> ```
> Tokens Earned | Reward
> :---------------------------------------:
> 10           | Upside-Down Man Photo Item 
> 100          | "Salute" Gesture
> 300          | Worker Costume
> 500          | Miner's Technique Talisman
> 1000         | Traffic Cone Photo Item
> 2000         | School Uniform 1.0 Costume
> 3000         | Fisher's Recipe Talisman
> 4000         | "You There" Gesture
> 5000         | Shifter 1.0 Costume
> 6000         | Unlimited Potential Talisman
> ```

Not only will the Dusty Token restricted items be removed, but the Treasure Chest rewards also be **near impossible to find** after the removal of the hint system. [This Gravity Rush Central article](https://www.gravityrushcentral.com/2017/10/23/closure-gravity-rush-2s-online-services-may-introduce-another-problem-new-players/) details each of the items that are locked behind the treasure chests,

> ### Talismans
>
> - Amaranth Treasure
> - Aqua Treasure
> - Carmine Treasure
> - Celadon Treasure
> - Cerulean Treasure
> - Cinereous Treasure
> - Coral Treasure
> - Crimson Treasure
> - Indigo Treasure
> - Sable Treasure
> - Scarlet Treasure
> - Slate Treasure
> - Taupe Treasure
> - Turquoise Treasure
> - Violet Treasure
> - Viridian Treasure
>
> ### Photo Items
>
> - Bucket
> - Fire Hydrant
> - Flower Pot
> - Gas Canister
> - Hog’s Head
> - Mailbox
> - Planter
> - Standing Sign
> - Vending Machine
> - Big Box (this is the name listed when you open the box, the photo item itself is actually called “Large Box”)
>
> ### Gestures
>
> - Backflip
> - Donut
> - Hip Attack
> - Skewer
> - Tongue Out
> - Wink
>
> ### Furniture (Available starting from Chapter 3)
>
> - Antique Mirror
> - Basket
> - Bookshelf
> - Candle Chandelier
> - Cat Bed
> - Dining Chair
> - Hanger Stand
> - Houseplant
> - Kettle
> - Modern Bed
> - Mosaic Curtains
> - Mosaic Mirror
> - Phone
> - Pipe Bed
> - Polka Dot Curtains
> - Polka Dot Floor Mat
> - Ratty Bed
> - Ratty Floor Mat
> - Rimmed Mirror
> - Rough Table
> - Round Table
> - Shaggy Floor Mat
> - Stool
> - Succulent Plant
> - Frame Mirror
>
> ### Talismans (Available starting from Chapter 3)
>
> - Ultimate Explorer

*Note: I will update this post if I hear any information regarding a post-shutdown fix*

Comment: Tables are difficult to format. If anyone has a better formatting technique, feel free to edit.